# How to create custom notification with reply and like button in android

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

I have implemented push notification in my app. But we want add on like and reply button in over notification.

Answer (score 4):

You can add buttons to notifications using the add action method in your notification builder.

eg:

```
                    val yesIntent = Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver::class.java)

                    yesIntent.action = "MY.INTENT.FILTER"


                    val mPendingYesIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, Random().nextInt(), yesIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
```

Now you set the pending intent as the action of your notification builder. (Note i have made the pending intent to be captured by a broadcast receiver, you can use a service or something else as per your need)

You can add the pending intent as follows:

```
              val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.your_notif_icon)
                        .setContentTitle("your title")
                        .setContentText("your text")
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                        .addAction(R.drawable.icon_needed_for_button, "Like", mPendingYesIntent)
```

For inline reply, i would suggest making the notification a remote input field

reference doc: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#reply-action